# Fields that not used in`GROUP BY` is not reachable in HAVING clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

Fields that not used in `GROUP BY` are not usable in `SELECT` but they're usable in `WHERE`. This makes sense since `WHEN` comes before `GROUP BY` but shouldn't `HAVING` has to be able to access "other" columns of the row.

### Example

Below is valid.

```sql
select fid, count(*)
from class
inner join faculty using (fid)
group by fid
having every(class.room = 'R128')
```

But can't do this.

```sql
select fid, count(*)
from class
inner join faculty using (fid)
group by fid
having class.room = 'R128' // Changed Line
```

Error message of above snippet:

```
RROR:  column "class.room" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 7: having class.room = 'R128'
               ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 86
```

I didn't fall into [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), I want to know why this is impossible (Question is correct with `every()` later is wrong in semantics too for the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`having` is used to filter the *result* of the grouping.

However the `room` column is  neither part of an aggregate nor part of the `GROUP BY`.

`every()` is an aggregate function an thus it's allowed in the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use aggregate functions in a HAVING clause and “every” is an aggregate function